# Display dynamic youtube video using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am building a video FAQ page for my website.

My objective is to have an embedded Youtube video at the top of the page with a list of questions underneath it. When a user clicks on a specific question, I'd like the page to refresh and display the video that corresponds with that question shown in the place where I have the youtube embedded at the top of the page.

Has anyone done this before and have any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Comment: You can change the url of the embedded video on click of the specific question.

Comment: Do you have an example code snippet of how I would do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can code it in this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="youtube" width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1">
</iframe>

<h2>something</h2>
<p onclick=qus1()>Question 1</p>
<p onclick=qus2()>Question 2</p>

<script>
  function qus1(){               
       document.getElementById('youtube').src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GibiNy4d4gc?autoplay=1";
  }
  function qus2(){
       document.getElementById('youtube').src ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o6Jo2hW6gHI?autoplay=1";
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped.